# Spring/JPA twice uniderectional not working, because of @JoinColumn(nullable = false)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entity, one-to-many

I have problem with unidirectional mapping and need help.

I have 2 Entities with the same unidirectional mapping.

The first one:

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "massnahme_id", nullable = false)
private Set<VerortungDAO> verortungen = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

The second one:

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "massnahmen_verbund_id", nullable = false)
private Set<VerortungDAO> verortungen = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

If I try to save one Entity, hibernate throws an Exception because of the second Entity definition (not null).

> org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a
> null or transient value

If I change the JoinColumn to nullable = true, then the unidirectional mapping not working and the list is not saved in DB.
What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Make the associations bidirectional and map the to-one association in `VerortungDAO`, or if you don't want that, at least map the FK-columns. If you map it bidirectional, use `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "...")`. Either way, you will have to initialize the two to-one associations or FK-columns on the `VerortungDAO` objects.

PS: An entity isn't a DAO (data access object), so the naming `xxDAO` is quite confusing for an entity.